# wordpress/php - Ajax/Jquery send gravity forms input fields/drop down to another page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I want to populate the gravity form that users fill in, dynamically in one of the pages for viewing based on the first drop down select value. For this, In all the pages for viewing the form's content, I need to know the drop down input that has been selected. Here's what I've done so far:

-In the gravityforms.php 's GFForms class:
In the init function I registered my hook as such:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

and after "maybe_process_form()" static function in this file, I added my_enqueue:

```
function my_enqueue() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url( '/js/ajaxSendField.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
        array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
}
```

-Created a file named ajaxSendField.js in the js folder:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

jQuery('#input_2_3').bind('onchange', function (){
ajaxSend(this.form);
});
});

function ajaxSend(form1)
{

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var data = {
        'action': 'my_enqueue'
    };

    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) { 
    });
});
}
</script>
```

In which, input_2_3 is the id of the drop down select when I inspect it via chrome. So far, the onchange event should have been set in the form, if we want to pass the value by selecting a drop down menu, rather than submitting the form. But, when I view the page source, it doesn't show up.
-In the template of the page for viewing the submitted value called custompage1.php, I have added the code below, above its footer:

```
<?php
echo "Hi";
echo $_POST['input_3']."<br>"."Bye";
?>
```

In which input_3 is the select's name. But upon form submission(Ajax), I only get 
Hi
Bye
What could be the problem though? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear on what you are trying to achieve, but changing the form values based upon a select is something you could achieve without the need for an ajax call to the server. Anyway, that isn't what you asked....

```
function ajaxSend(form1)
{
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var data = {
            'action': 'my_enqueue'
        };
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) { 
        });
    });
}
```

There's some work to be done with your code, a few points to get you started. In the code above you have nested a function within a function. `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` means once the page has finished loading, do this. It doesn't belong inside another function.

```
var data = {
'action': 'my_enqueue'
}
```

The data var is what you are telling your ajax call to send to the server. In Wordpress the action parameter specifies the action you want Wordpress to execute (more on that below), but you aren't sending any other data along with it. Based on your aim I would have thought you should be also sending the value of the select box at least.

```
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) { 
});
```

This posts the data, but you haven't included any code to specify what to do with the response. Even if the server was sending you back all the data you want nothing will happen unless you tell your ajax call how to handle the output

As for the Wordpress side of it... Let's start with this

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

This will only enqueue your scripts on admin pages, is that what you really want or would `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );` be better?
Your `wp_localize_script` parameters don't match the values in your ajax call. I recommend you re-read the documentation to understand how this works.

Last point from me, you have added no ajax action. These take the form of

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_action', 'my_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_action', 'my_function' );
```

These tell Wordpress what function you want to tie to your ajax request. The first is for users who aren't logged in, the second for users who are.

Stick at it. You have made a good start, but you have a little way left to go. Good luck.

Comment: As I'm a noob in php/Ajax, sorry for my mistakes, and thanks. I don't want to change the form values based upon a select, rather, I want when the form submits to another page(which I also don't know how to specify the other page, because I cannot insert e.g. action="anotherpage.php" in wordpress), I have access to select value on the anotherpage, so that I load the form data if that select value is a specific value.

Comment: 1) How could I send the select value in data variable by its name,id,etc.? 2) Because the ajax response is not required in the form's page, I think I don't need it here, but is there a way to insert all the form entries with a specific select value in the database here?3)Could you shoot me on wp_localize_script example regarding my ajax call?

Comment: 4) Are the places where I've called add_action and declared the action right?